# How to manually upgrade firmware (currently on Big Sur, update from Catalina broke Bluetooth)

Tags: bluetooth, software-update, big-sur, firmware

Ever since I've upgraded to Big Sur, my Bluetooth hasn't been working normally. I tried resetting my MBP 2016 and it didn't change anything, so after chatting with Apple Support, we've both reached the conclusion is that the firmware is corrupted.

Now, I'm wondering whether it's possible to update it or reset it myself, via Terminal or some other magical tool.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would have thought you could download/install firmware updates from the Apple Support/Downloads page. Usually firmware updates are made in conjunction with system updates but sometimes there's firmware updates for specific models that aren't packaged with the system update. I suggest you check the Apple support/downloads page and maybe await the Big Sur update 11.1 (which is nearing the end of it's beta testing with developers).